# Getting error while using fgets in ansi c to open file

Tags: c

I'm trying to create/open a file using c. I enter the name using the fgets command, so I can not overflow the buffer, like this:

```
void main() {
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    char * fileName = (char *) calloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    fgets(fileName, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(fileName, "w");
    if(inputFile==NULL) perror(fileName);
}
```

Using the debugger, I can see that the value I entered for the name of the file, is the one I wish, but the fopen function returns NULL pointer and I get the "Invalid argument" error. If I use `scanf("%s", fileName)` instead there is no problem and the file is created but in this way I could overflow the buffer. Any ideas why the first example is not working?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string read by `fgets` might have a newline at the end. You'll have to remove it before you use the string in `fopen`.

[How to remove the newline at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score 2):

`fgets()` treats newlines differently than `scanf("%s")` or `gets()`. Unlike them, `fgets()` includes the newline in the string. After typing the filename, you pressed enter which probably included the newline into your filename, hence rendering it invalid.